# Not able to receive email from personal email domain

Tags: apex-email-service

I have create a email service to which I have a class attached to create contact record. When I send email from Gmail, redifmail I am able to receive email and contact is created but when I send a email from my personal company email id (myname@company.com) with company domain name I am not able to receive email id. Please guide me whet is the issue or what I am missing out to receive email from company domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have added your domain name / email address to 'Accept Emails From' on the edit page of the Email Service.

Also, against each email address you have active make sure that your email address domain name is listed in the 'Accept Email From' field too.

Comment: yes i have added the company domain name on both place on email service as  but still the email is not received from gmail, rediffmail but not from company domain.

Comment: Have you checked the debug logs or are you getting any bounce backs?  Can you post a screen grab of the email services page?

Comment: No am not getting any debug log getting bounce the email error.Do you have any solution on that.